# Working directory not set correctly for multi module Java maven project

Tags: java, maven

I have following multi module project structure:

```
ProjectName
+--Config
+--Pom.xml
+--Api
   +--src\Main\Java\SomeRunnerClass.java
   +--Pom.xml
+--Tests
   +--src\Test\Java\TestsRunner.java
   +--Pom.xml
```

When i run:

```
mvn compile -pl Api exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=SomeRunnerClass
```

Working directory is correctly seen as \ProjectName and i can use files from Config directory

But when i run

```
mvn compile test
```

Which runns TestsRunner (cucumber runner) the working directory is seen as \ProjectName\Tests so i can't see \ProjectName\Config directory and all tests artefacts are saved to Tests instead of ProjectName directory

Is there a way to change  working directory when running maven tests?

Comment: Where is the `Config` needed?  If it's needed in Api you have to put into Api...usually this belongs into `src/main/resources`...

Comment: I use this both in Api and Tests, there are json files with configuration to run tests and to prepare environment which is done in Api

Comment: Why kind of tests? Unit tests or integration tests? Furthermore you should make a separate module `config` where you put the needed information into `src/main/resources` and add this to the other modules which need it as a test scoped dependency...

Comment: But they are not part of project, they are injected there by separate tool. And they have to be in ProjectName folder as well as tests artefacts.

Comment: Can you show the real part or at least an example of those things..otherwise it's hard to understand.. What do you mean they are not part of the project? They are used for tests so they are part of the project ?...?

Comment: But this is not important in this case. I want to know if it is possible to change working directory when i run maven test which run class from one of modules.

Comment: @Kamil1014 It _is_ important because it seems like you are trying to build around Maven, while khmarbaise offers you an approach to solve your original problem (which is not the working directory, but running the tests properly) in a Maven way.

Comment: I have class which search all json files in given directory also in some const path like c:\config and they are created dynamically so i dont want separate module or even attach them. Also Tests module creates allure-results in working directory. And i would like to use it in ProjectName directory not in ProjectName\Tests. They are also used by Jenkins and other tools so i have to store them in main directory

Answer (score -1):

I have achieved this by adding workingDirectory to maven-surfire configuration in child pom file:

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-surefire-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <workingDirectory>${project.basedir}/../</workingDirectory>
...
```

Comment: that solution is a hack. You should do what was already suggested in the comments, which is create a Config module and put the files in there to `src/main/resources`. Then set a dependency to that module in `Api\pom.xml` and `Tests\pom.xml`.

Comment: Also, I don't see why you want to separate the tests in different modules from your api. Could you elaborate? To me it seems like you are setting yourself up for all kinds of problems down the line with this solution

Comment: Api module is used in few projects. That is why i wanted to have it separated. But config is not my only problem. I wanted to have the same path when running `mvn compile -pl Api exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=SomeRunnerClass` and  running `mvn test`. Now it is working correctly

Comment: tests are not packaged in the final artifact. You don't need to separate them from your actual code